# How do I remove a value from the prompt list in cognos report studio

Tags: cognos-10

I created a value prompt in cognos report studio just as the one below.

[Class Code] in (?p_Class_Code?)

when I run the report, of course I get the prompt

Class Code
Provide a Value:
A123
B456
C789
D101
E123

What if I want to remove C789 from the list of the value prompt? It is a NULL Class Code that's why I want to remove it so that users won't encounter it and use it among the Class Codes.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is four months old and I'm guessing you've found a solution. If not, you need to:

1. Create a query containing the column you want to filter on that excludes the value you don't want your user to see and select. This is done via a filter such as [Class Code] <> 'C789'
2. Add your own value prompt, most likely on a prompt page, and specify the query you created in step 1 as the source.